# Angular ng-click works only once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class, ng-hide

I need to switch between to div's. Div `class="wrapper"` must be visible by default. Div `class="form"` must be shown after admin approve. The problem is when i click on `<a ng-click="toggle()">` it works only once, and no reaction after. If i will add some `ng-hide` to 'wrapper', `ng-click` works, but show/hide only 'form'. `<a>` must be shown after controller response, like `class="form"`.

HTML:

```
<div class="body" ng-class="{'show': show && showTemp}">
        <a ng-click="toggle()"></a>
        <div class="form"></div>
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    display: none;
}

.wrapper {
    display: block;
}

.show .form {
    display: block;
}

.show .wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.show = false;
 $scope.showTemp = true;


 // response from admin
 $scope.$on('$show', function(e,data) {
                $scope.show = true;
                $scope.available = data;
            });


    // this click by user
    $scope.toggle = function() {
            $scope.showTemp = !$scope.showTemp;
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you do something simpler like:

```
<div class="body" ng-init="showForm = false">
        <a ng-click="showForm = available && ? false : !showForm">Click</a>
        <div class="form" ng-show="showForm"></div>
        <div class="wrapper" ng-hide="showForm"></div>
</div>
```

By using `ngInit` I'm setting a default value to `showForm` to false (You can do it from the controller as-well (`$scope.showForm = false;`) and then I toggle the `ng-hide` class (Which is found in `angular.css` any simply defined as `.ng-hide {display: none;}`) to show/hide the form and the wrapper DIVs.

When you click on the button the following condition is evaluated: `showForm = available && ? false : !showForm` - The `showForm` will always be hidden if there is no data available, and if there is data avalable, it will toggle between the form and the wrapper.

You can also add `ng-show="available"` to the button so it's only visible once there's data, because before it does nothing. A working example:

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setData = function(data) {
    $scope.available = data;
    $scope.showForm  = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="body" ng-init="showForm = false">
        <a ng-show="available" ng-click="showForm = !showForm">Click</a>
        <br>
        <div class="form" ng-show="showForm">THIS IS THE FORM<br>{{available | json}}</div>
        <div class="wrapper" ng-hide="showForm">THIS IS THE WRAPPER</div>
  
  <button ng-hide="available" ng-click="setData({val: 'test'})">SET MOCK DATA</button>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: <div class="form"> must be shown only after response from controller: $scope.$on('$show', function(e,data) {
                $scope.show = true;
                $scope.available = data;
            });

Comment: So not sure I understand - What should happen before the response from the controller ` $scope.$on('$show', ,,,` when you click on the link? And btw - Did you intentionally wrapped the form and the wrapper inside the `A` tag?

Comment: 1. Wrapper visible by default. Form - hidden
2. When controller responce: Form - visible, wrapper - hidden
3. When <a> click, after controller responce  - just switch between them. visible/hiiden

Comment: I have added some changes, can you check please? If not, i'll remove my answer because I have to go and won't be able to answer for the next couple of horse

Comment: One update came, <a> must be hidden by default and shown only after controller response once. After appearing <a> must be always visible

Comment: @Serhiog.Lazin In that case add `ng-show="available"` to the `<a>` to make it hidden until the data exist (Where you set `$scope.available = data;` inside the event listener in the controller)

Comment: Thanks, but main issue still present.. ng-click still works only once

Comment: @Serhiog.Lazin I have added a working example - note that the `SET MOCK DATA` button is there to simulate the event where you get the the data in your app

Comment: The same with your code. Click works only first time and then any reaction. I guess this 'on' event doesn't allow to change variable, when setted it inside "$scope.$on('$show', function(e,data) {
                $scope.showForm  = true;
                $scope.available = data;
            });"

Comment: @Serhiog.Lazin After you click on the `SET MOCK DATA` you can click on the `click` link to toggle between the two, it's working fine in my example (I have editted to example to make the link more noticeable)

Comment: Your example is absolutely amazing! It works. I have tried it one in one, but still have an issue with ones click working, as i wrote in previous comment it can be because $on event doesn't allow to change variable, after assignment inside it. $on - started and hangs.

Comment: Where/How do you `$broadcast` the `$show` event? Can you edit your question and include that part too? I feel like I don't understand something basic here - Not sure if it's because of lack of details of some sort of stupidity on my side

Comment: It is sad to be dumb by my side. You are absolutely correct! Your code works very fine. Thank you!